# How Add my iPhone application on international keybord?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

I want to create one keyboard application that is not in iPhone international keyboard, but I don't know how I add this application to international keyboard, I want to do one work like emoji application, but my app is not emotion!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want to install your keyboard in the system so it's available to any app?

Comment: Yes, I want add my keyboard on system but I'm not sure that is available to any app. There are sample on Apple Store so I think it is possible for any app.

Comment: Your app can include it's own custom keyboard for it's own use.

Comment: I believe I able use my keyboard in all application, Did you see emoji application? this keyboard come up from all applications.

Comment: The Emoji keyboard is already on the system because of Japanese users.  All the Emoji application does is enable the keyboard. It doesn't install anything even if the screen say installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application can display a custom keyboard from any TextView or TextField by returning a custom UIView (that would be your keyboard) from the inputView property on those text input views. There is no existing keyboard to inherit from, so you'll have to implement everything your self.